# Google Tasks pane does not show on calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm trying to manage my tasks from the calendar view of google.
My default view does not show the tasks.
When I add "&hl=en" to the URL this solves the problem, but this is not the default google takes me to.

I already tried changing the langauge and country setting to US and "english".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your default language of search home to English & google.com.

This is done through clicking the `Google.com in English` at the bottom of the page.

Google will update the language you work with.